# Laravel | MySQL sort and delete by created_at

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm fairly new to Laravel so forgive me if I'm asking something very obvious.

I have a database that I iterate over using Eloquent and I need to delete everything in the database that's older than 30 days and I'm clearly doing something wrong.

```
$dataArr = Data::orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
    foreach($dataArr as $data){
        if($data['created_at'] < strtotime('-30 days')){
            $data->delete();
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
```

The code does not seem to go into the loop at all and I don't quite understand how to do this task

Comment: `$dataArr` is the query builder, not the results, since you never use `->get()`. There are easier ways to do this, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, `$dataArr` is the query builder, not the results, since you never use `->get()`.

```
$dataArr = Data::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get(); // now contains all of the records
```

However, there's an easier way to delete the records without going through them one-by-one.

```
DB::table('data_table')
    ->where('created_at', '<', 
            Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->toDateTimeString())
    ->delete();
```

Comment: Carbon is built into Laravel, so you should be able to use it just like that.